# Docker-Machine stuck on creating default

Tags: macos, docker, docker-machine

I'm trying to start the default machine of Docker on Mac OSX.

Everytime i'm trying to start a new default machine by command:

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default
```

of using `Docker Quick Start Terminal` It stucks on

```
(default) Creating SSH key...
```

This is the output:

```
Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
(default) Copying /Users/avivpaz/.docker/machine/cache/boot2docker.iso to /Users/avivpaz/.docker/machine/machines/default/boot2docker.iso...
(default) Creating VirtualBox VM...
(default) Creating SSH key...
```

This is my OSX and Docker versions:

```
Mac 10.11.3    
docker-machine version 0.6.0, build e27fb87
```

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be followed by [issue 2788](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/2788) and more related to VirtualBox than docker machine.

Try and reboot the Mac, or make sure there is no VBox... process.

Comment: Also watch https://blog.docker.com/2016/03/docker-for-mac-windows-beta/, which resolves a lot of issues that were caused by VirtualBox

Answer (score 0):

First, just delete the **boot2docker.iso** from *~/cache* directory and once again restart the docker terminal. If will download the fresh latest boot2docker.iso and you are good to go.
If it's not working manually download the [latest boot2docker.iso](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases) and place it into the above directory of cache

```
/Users/{user}/.docker/machine/cache/

$ ~/.docker/machine/cache

$ ls
boot2docker.iso
```

And, finally run to create an virtual machine,

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default
```

And, again, you are good to go. Hope this helps.